# Converting date and time string to appropriate format for arithmetic calculations

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I am using Python and I have dates in the table of the type '2013-06-24 17:04:28' stored as strings and I want to do things such as subtract and average them.

I dont care much about the time.

What is the appropriate format to convert the string to and how do I do it?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Max.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime

Comment: @LajosArpad it's not because it's pandas-specific, however it may be a dupe of another question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pandas has it's own Timestamp object. You can convert strings, or entire columns (Series), to Timestamps using the `to_datetime` function:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date_col'])
```

*See ["converting to Timestamps" section of the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#converting-to-timestamps).*

Note: you can convert to Timestamps when reading in your DataFrame e.g. using [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html).

It works with your date format:

```
In [11]: pd.to_datetime('2013-06-24 17:04:28')
Out[11]: Timestamp('2013-06-24 17:04:28', tz=None)
```

Comment: So if I now 'df['date_col'].groupby(df['som_categorical_var']) - can I .mean() on the group object over dates?

Comment: maybe `df['date_col'].groupby(['som_categorical_var', 'date_col']).mean()`, maybe? Ask as different question if it's not working, since it's rather different from this one

Comment: @AndyHayden How do you get to all the SO questions so *fast*?

Comment: @AndyHayden Have you actually played that?? Or maybe you play that on a regular basis :)

Answer (score 0):

```
time.strptime("2013-06-24 17:04:28", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

then you can use [python's time module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#module-time)